# $R(\alpha) = \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)}$ achieves $\beta \in \mathbb{C}, n$ times.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $R(\alpha) = \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)}, \ \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$.

$R$ is rational and $f(\alpha), g(\alpha)$ are polynomials with no factors in common. Define $n=$ deg$(R(\alpha)) = $ max deg $(f(\alpha), g(\alpha))$.

I want to show that each value, $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ is achieved $n$ times by $R(\alpha)$ on $\mathbb{C}$. I specifically don't want to use the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

**Idea using the Argument Principle:**

First let $ \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} = \beta$ and define $P(\alpha)= g(\alpha)\beta - f(\alpha)$.

Now consider  $P(\gamma(t))$, where $\gamma$ is a circle of radius $\rho$ centered at the origin. As $\rho$ increases we have a dominating term (in whichever polynomial) of degree $n$. A determination of our argument is then $nt$, thus our change in argument is $2\pi n$. We have then that, $P(\alpha)$ achieves $n$ zeros, or $\beta$ is achieved $n$ times (counting multiplicity).

Thx!